# Best practices to store user object after authentication process

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, firebase-realtime-database

So, I found asking myself this question several times while building iOS applications. Essentially, most of the applications that I have been developing involves Firebase for data storage and maintain a shared instance to store user object [locally] upon authentication process completes.

Main concern with this process is that upon authentication process the user object contains only relative user information such as email, full name etc. But throughout other app features, the app may be required to update the user object once in a while. And, with such approach, I had always end up maintaining both parties remote & local stored user object.

Is there a proper method/practice on how to handle such problem ?

Comment: You're asking for help with code you wrote, so I recommend adding the minimal code that reproduces what you're asking about to your question. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Auth0 stores user information for your tenant in a hosted cloud database, or you can choose to store user data in your own custom external database.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue if not user storage. The main issue that I'm currently facing is that after use authentication and store local user object locally. At some point of the app, I have to sync both local user object and firebase user node. Which I personally don't want.

Answer (score 1):

**You should check Auth0, I reckon that is the "proper method" that you're searching for.**

Auth0 is a cloud-based platform that provides authentication and authorization as a service. As an authentication provider, Auth0 enables developers to easily implement and customize login and authorization security.

Why use Firebase and Auth0 Together?

One thing to notice is that Firebase does provide authentication features out of the box.

I quote:

> You should consider Auth0 with a custom Firebase token if you:
>
> - Already have Auth0 implemented and want to add realtime capabilities    to your app
> - Need to easily use issued tokens to secure a back end that is not    provided by Firebase
> - Need to integrate social identity providers beyond just Google,    Facebook, Twitter, and GitHub
> - Need to integrate enterprise identity providers, such as Active    Directory, LDAP, ADFS, SAMLP, etc.
> - Need a customized authentication flow
> - Need robust user management with APIs and an admin-friendly dashboard
> - Want to be able to dynamically enrich user profiles
> - Want features like customizable passwordless login, multifactor    authentication, breached password security, anomaly detection, etc.
> - Must adhere to compliance regulations such as HIPAA, GDPR, SOC2, etc.
> - Must adhere to compliance regulations such as HIPAA, GDPR, SOC2, etc.
>
> Essentially, Firebase's basic authentication providers should suffice
>   if you have a very simple app with bare-bones authentication needs and
>   are only using Firebase databases.

Let me know if you need any further help. Now go and have an awesome day!

Comment: Auth0 isn't simple enough to comply GDPR?